# Error when creating dataframe from two columns in Python panda

Tags: python, pandas

when i try to create dataframe from two columns i.e. pids and SalePrice I get error  "Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional". I think the error is coming because these two data series are in different format like below. Please help how can i make these data series same

```
ksubmission = pd.DataFrame({'Id':pids,'SalePrice':predictions_kaggle})
```

Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional

> > pids.shape

(1459,)

> > predictions_kaggle.shape

(1459, 1)

predictions_kaggle is in below format

```
array([[115901.20520943],
       [144313.70246636],
       [165320.94012928],
       ...,
       [155759.14767572],
       [111175.64223766],
       [249104.99042467]])
```

while pids is in below format

```
0       1461
1       1462
2       1463
3       1464
4       1465
        ... 
1454    2915
1455    2916
1456    2917
1457    2918
1458    2919
Name: Id, Length: 1459, dtype: int64
```

Comment: have you tried using `pids.values` instead of `pids`?

Comment: Or have you tried to use `predictions_kaggle.flatten()` to make it 1-dimensional?

Comment: I still get same error with pids.values

Comment: predictions_kaggle.flatten() worked.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do this if the lengths are the same:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.DataFrame(predictions_kaggle, index=pids).reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'Id', 0:'SalePrice'}) 

or

pd.DataFrame({'Id':pids,'SalePrice':np.ndarray.flatten(predictions_kaggle)})
```

Comment: but pids shouldnt be index.. instead it should be a column

Comment: does it work though, we can rename it a column by reseting index. It also let me know how to format it

Comment: @user2774120 i changed it. It might not be the end solution, but it might work. Otherwise i believe you have to flatten the list with np.ndarray.flatten

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your `predictions_kaggle` array is not a 1-D array but rather a 2-D one. As proof, the shape of a 1-D array should be in the form `(n,)` but instead you have `(n,1)` which indicates that each line of your array is a single value inside an array. A quick fix to this is by flattening the array, which will turn it into a 1-D array:

```py
ksubmission = pd.DataFrame({'Id':pids,'SalePrice':predictions_kaggle.flatten()})
```

Hope this helps.